# How Can I Regex Match The Common Name of This DN?

Tags: regex, powershell-3.0

Given the string `CN=Smith\, John,OU=Users,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com`, I am seeking to match the complete common name, including the comma after it. I'm really trying to remove this part, so matching the other part would work too.

The result after removal or filter ought to be `OU=Users,OU=IT,DC=contoso,DC=com`.

I tried `^.+(?=,OU=)` with no flags but this captures `CN=Some\, Guy,OU=Users`

The language/regex standard is PowerShell, but I can figure out the conversion from another standard, so any solution is likely better than where I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this: `^.+?(?=,OU=),` and it shell match the entire string until the OU part.

Comment: Marvelous. That did the trick. I modified it a bit to allow for matching cases where the next part is not an OU. I'll edit your answer for visibility of the final solution. Thanks @Sniffer!. Edit: Until my edit is reviewed, I'll put the answer here: `^.+?(?=,\w.=),`